# Create A cron Expression for Weekly

Tags: jakarta-ee

Suppose I pass the value like `2009-07-13T18:00:00`

I have to create a `cron` expression using Java to get like  `* * 18 13 07 2009` ?

Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `crontab(5)` expression:

> ```
> * * 18 13 07 2009
> ```

will execute every minute of every hour on the 18th day of the 13th month, on the 2009th day in the week. :)

Jul 13, 2009, was a Monday. A `crontab` entry that executes every week, with that as your starting point, would be:

```
0 18 * * 1
```

That would execute at 18:00 on the first day of every week. (Sunday is `0`.)

`cron` has no notion of 'start' and 'stop' dates. Things only ever execute in the future. And when you want them to stop, you remove the entry. It is *very* primitive, and something like "next-to-last Friday of the month" is cumbersome, but it's amazing what five little numbers can do.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron format is not clear. * * 18 13 07 2009 is not a valid cron entry.

You can use SimpleDateFormat to convert the value to a desired format.

So, in your case, you could use something as below.

```
String s = "2009-07-13T18:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
Date d = sf.parse();

//now convert to the format you want
sf = new SimpleDateFormat("* * HH dd mm yyyy");
String cronEntry = sf.format(d);
```

But before you do this, check your cron entry and find out exactly how you want to setup the cron timing. The example you have given is invalid.

Comment: 2009-07-13T18:00:00  Now i got ur point but will it get me in the format of Cron Expression